# MVC 4 RedirectToAction Generates Wrong URL

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, redirecttoaction

I am having a problem with `RedirectToAction`. I have the following simple controller class. `Index` method displays a list of Groups. `Create` creates a new group and adds it to the database. This works fine and shows up in the list when it is redirected back to `Index`. The problem is that the URL once it renders `Index` is still using the one from the `Create`: `/Group/Create`. I think it is actually redirecting to `Index` properly and then immediately flashing to the `Create` action because it shows the right content for `Index`. Any idea what would cause this? I have no custom routes defined, so I am pretty sure it isn't a routing issue. I suspect it is an AJAX problem.

```
public class GroupController : Controller
{
    private ModelDb db = new ModelDb();

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Create(Group group)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Groups.Add(group);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(group);
    }
}
```

Comment: _I suspect it is an AJAX problem._? What ajax code do you have?

Comment: I am using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: You mentioned AJAX. Are you posting using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an AJAX problem created by JQuery Mobile. I should have done more testing before posting the question, but maybe it will help someone else. I disabled posting the data using AJAX and the problem went away. Now I have to update a bunch of forms to disable it everywhere.

So I now use the following code to begin a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Group", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false" }))
```